# Hibernate: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, mappingexception

I have a database called db_produts and I mapped eclipse through hibernate using configuration files ".hbm.xml". I set the configuration file and I created the HibernateUtil.java class to generate the session. I created a class called HibernateMain.java should set a table in this database, the table "ingredient" and corresponds to "ingredient.java" class. The problem is that when I start this class gives me this error log:

```js
> ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: BankAccount.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: RtFactoryProduct.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: RtDispenserProduct.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: MessageHistory.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: User.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Category.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Factory.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: StaffLogin.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: GeoArea.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: RtIngredientProduct.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: RtFamilyProduct.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: UserLogin.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: DispenserState.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Product.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Capacity.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Producer.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: StaffType.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Family.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Inner.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: RtUserProduct.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Ingredient.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: RtStaffDispenser.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Dispenser.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Staff.hbm.xml
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Hibernate Configuration loaded
Hibernate serviceRegistry created
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_products]
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
ott 29, 2016 8:26:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
ott 29, 2016 8:26:31 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
ott 29, 2016 8:26:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
ott 29, 2016 8:26:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
ott 29, 2016 8:26:31 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at it.jack.fdd.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:42)
 at it.jack.fdd.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:124)
 at it.jack.fdd.main.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
 at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
 at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
 at it.jack.fdd.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:35)
 ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
 ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for fkcategory in class it.jack.fdd.model.Product
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:310)
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:304)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:323)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:411)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:200)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
 ... 20 more
```

HibernateUtil.Class:

```js
package it.jack.fdd.util;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import it.jack.fdd.model.*;

//import com.journaldev.hibernate.model.Employee1;

public class HibernateUtil {

 //XML based configuration
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 
 //Annotation based configuration
 private static SessionFactory sessionAnnotationFactory;
 
 //Property based configuration
 private static SessionFactory sessionJavaConfigFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
         Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
         configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
         System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration loaded");
         
         ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
         System.out.println("Hibernate serviceRegistry created");
         
         SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
         
            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionAnnotationFactory() {
     try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
         Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
         configuration.configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml");
         System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation Configuration loaded");
         
         ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
         System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation serviceRegistry created");
         
         SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
         
            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
 }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionJavaConfigFactory() {
     try {
     Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
  
  //Create Properties, can be read from property files too
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_products");
  props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
  props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "root");
  props.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
  
  configuration.setProperties(props);
  
  //we can set mapping file or class with annotation
  //addClass(Employee1.class) will look for resource
  // com/journaldev/hibernate/model/Employee1.hbm.xml (not good)
  
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(BankAccount.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Capacity.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Category.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Dispenser.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(DispenserState.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Factory.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Family.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(GeoArea.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ingredient.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Inner.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(MessageHistory.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Producer.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Product.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(RtDispenserProduct.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(RtFactoryProduct.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(RtFamilyProduct.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(RtIngredientProduct.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(RtStaffDispenser.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(RtUserProduct.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Staff.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(StaffLogin.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(StaffType.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
  configuration.addAnnotatedClass(UserLogin.class);
  
  ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
     System.out.println("Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created");
     
     SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
     
        return sessionFactory;
     }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
 }
    
 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  if(sessionFactory == null) sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }
 
 public static SessionFactory getSessionAnnotationFactory() {
  if(sessionAnnotationFactory == null) sessionAnnotationFactory = buildSessionAnnotationFactory();
        return sessionAnnotationFactory;
    }
 
 public static SessionFactory getSessionJavaConfigFactory() {
  if(sessionJavaConfigFactory == null) sessionJavaConfigFactory = buildSessionJavaConfigFactory();
        return sessionJavaConfigFactory;
    }
 
}
```

ingredient.java:

```js
package it.jack.fdd.model;
// Generated 29-ott-2016 12.52.16 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final

/**
 * Ingredient generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Ingredient implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer idingredient;
 private String name;

 public Ingredient() {
 }

 public Ingredient(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public Integer getIdingredient() {
  return this.idingredient;
 }

 public void setIdingredient(Integer idingredient) {
  this.idingredient = idingredient;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

}
```

Ingredient.hbm.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 29-ott-2016 12.52.16 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="it.jack.fdd.model.Ingredient" table="ingredient" catalog="db_products" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idingredient" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idingredient" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

HibernateMain.java

```js
package it.jack.fdd.main;



import org.hibernate.Session;


import it.jack.fdd.model.Ingredient;
import it.jack.fdd.util.HibernateUtil;

public class HibernateMain {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Ingredient ing = new Ingredient();
  ing.setName("Olio di palma");
  
  
  //Get Session
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  //start transaction
  session.beginTransaction();
  //Save the Model object
  session.save(ing);
  //Commit transaction
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  System.out.println("Ingredient ID="+ing.getIdingredient());
  
  //terminate session factory, otherwise program won't end
  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
 }

}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_products</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property>
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/BankAccount.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/RtFactoryProduct.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/RtDispenserProduct.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/MessageHistory.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/User.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Category.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Factory.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/StaffLogin.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/GeoArea.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/RtIngredientProduct.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/RtFamilyProduct.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/UserLogin.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/DispenserState.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Product.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Capacity.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Producer.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/StaffType.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Family.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Inner.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/it/jack/fddispenser/model/RtUserProduct.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Ingredient.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/RtStaffDispenser.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Dispenser.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="it/jack/fdd/model/Staff.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Somebody can help me to understand the problem? Thanks

Comment: can you provide the Hibernate.cfg.xml file code ?

Comment: can you please add the Product class

Comment: it seems like hibernate don't find some getter or setter in Product class.

Comment: Hibernate.cfg.xml updated

Comment: Ok @Killer! Now it works! Thanks so much!!!!